# sudo service apache2 restart: already running

Tags: 12.04, apache2, init.d

As the title says, when I run `sudo service apache2 restart`, the message returned says that `Apache is already running`. However, the service is stopped (if milliseconds later).

If I run `sudo service apache2 start`, everything works fine. I assume the script isn't waiting (long enough) for the process to end... I have two other servers (they're all 12.04) with the same config, exact same init file (I did a diff), and they don't exhibit this behavior.

Also interesting is that when I `start|stop|reload`, they don't return the `[OK]` message. What gives?

Comment: You need more info. What is the output when you try to restart/reload? Is it running at all? service apache2 status? have you ran sudo apt-get update/upgrade lately to make sure everything is updated for it?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for apache to get stuck and forget to remove its PID file (if it crashes, say).

Check if the file `/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid` exists. If it does, `rm` it.

Also check if there are apache processes running:

```
ps auxwww | grep apache
```

If there are, `kill -9` them. Then you should be able to start apache via `/etc/init.d/apache2 start`.

Comment: Consider using pgrep and pkill instead of `ps | grep`.